# Photoscroller for iPad

Tags: ipad, uiscrollview

Has anybody tried Apple's sample code PhotoScroller on iPad. I am getting a few errors, I guess it's due to the fact that the used libraries are iOS 4.0 only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Errors that I am getting:

1. error: request for member 'contentScaleFactor' in something not a structure or union
   on :: imageView.contentScaleFactor = 1.0;
2. error: incompatible types in initialization
   and warning: 'UIScreen' may not respond to '-scale'
   on :: CGFloat maxScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

Comment: Please post the exact errors, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: just edited my post to add errors I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are both iOS 4.0 specific things that help support the iPhone 4's retina display. Since you aren't building for iOS 4 or the iPhone 4, you can safely remove those calls or replace them with the value 1.0.

Comment: thanks! that worked. Any idea on how do we figure out the tiles neeeded for an image?